# primitive.M array to string? Responding to http request with the same structure

Tags: api, http, go, httpresponse

I'm doing a server api using GoLang, trying to manage and answer requests made. Using `net/http` and `github.com/gorilla/mux`.

When getting a request, I was using the following structure to create a response:

```
type Response struct {
    Error        bool   `json:"error"`
    Msg          string `json:"msg,omitempty"`
    Data         string `json:"data,omitempty"`
    AccessToken  string `json:"access_token,omitempty"`
    RefreshToken string `json:"refresh_token,omitempty"`
}
```

When retrieving several message type (another struct) from the Database I get a type `[]primitive.M`. My question is **how can I transform the `[]primitive.M` to a string to pass it as a data field?** I tried to use `msgsStr := Sprintf("%s", msgs)` but the response seemed to come out of format.

I'm assuming using the string type for Data field is correct since the objective is to pass json type information.

Partial example of result passing the []primitive.M directly:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "xxxxx",
        "datetime": {
            "T": 1589193727,
            "I": 1
        },
        "dislikes": "4",
        "latitude": 21.5,
        "likes": "32",
        "longitude": 12.2,
        "text": "message 123!",
        "user": "user#123121"
    },
    {
        "_id": "xxxxxx",
        "datetime": {
            "T": 1589193727,
            "I": 1
        },
        "dislikes": "4",
        "latitude": 14.4,
        "likes": "32",
        "longitude": 15,
        "text": "hello! 22",
        "user": "user#123121"
    },
```

After changing with Sprintf:

```
[map[_id:ObjectID(\"xxxxx\") datetime:{%!s(uint32=1589193727) %!s(uint32=1)} dislikes:4 latitude:%!s(float64=21.5) likes:32 longitude:%!s(float64=12.2) text:message 123! user:user#123121] map[_id:ObjectID(\"xxxxxx\") datetime:{%!s(uint32=1589193727) %!s(uint32=1)} dislikes:4 latitude:%!s(float64=14.4) likes:32 longitude:%!s(int32=15) text:hello! 22 user:user#123121]]
```

Comment: Try `fmt.Sprint(msgs)`.

Comment: @icza it does not make the weird characters, but it still shows it as a map with square brackets instead of curly: `[map[_id:ObjectID(\"xxxxx") datetime:{1589193727 1} dislikes:4 latitude:21.5 likes:32 longitude:12.2 text:message 123!! user:user#123121] map[_id:ObjectID(\"5ebad7c4fb2ccf79f2377b02\") datetime:{1589193727 1} dislikes:4 latitude:14.4 likes:32 longitude:15 text:hello! 22 user:user#123121]]`

Comment: Are you looking to print out the data as a JSON object? Why not simply `json.Marshal(msgs)`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes. I'm looking for the conventional way to do this type of operation as it is my first time using Go. Then should the "data" field in "response" have `[]byte` type? Or should I convert the return from `json.Marshal(msgs)` to string?

Comment: Just `jsonByte, err := json.Marshal(msgs)`, then, if there aren't any errors: `str := string(jsonByte)` should do. Also: using the `omitempty` in json tags only works if the fields it applies to are pointers (the nil value for a string is an empty string. If the field is missing, a pointer would be nil, if an empty string was explicitly sent, then the field would not be nil, but point to an empty string). If the `Data` field is supposed to be a JSON string, then use `json.RawMessage` (to avoid escaping JSON characters)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, it probably will be a json string. It works using `RawMessage` type. Thank you very much for that and for the hint on omitempty!

Comment: @Miguel NP, Posted most of this as an answer, with some more details. If that worked for you, perhaps mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, you're trying to set the `Data` field on your `Response` type to a string, which is also valid JSON. That's easy enough, but will require some changes:

```
type Response struct {
    Error        bool             `json:"error"`
    Msg          *string          `json:"msg,omitempty"`
    Data         *json.RawMessage `json:"data,omitempty"`
    AccessToken  *string          `json:"access_token,omitempty"`
    RefreshToken *string          `json:"refresh_token,omitempty"`
}
```

As you can see, I've changed most of your fields to pointers. This is because the `omitempty` tag doesn't really make sense unless the field is a pointer. An explicitly set empty string is not going to be omitted. The field *has* a value. Think of fields that are `int`, for example. Is a 0 value a value to omit? What if someone actually wants to pass in the value *0*? Pointer fields allow you to distinguish between missing/omitted fields, and nil values:

```
var resp Response
if err := json.Unmarshal(&resp, data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
if resp.Msg == nil {
    // msg was missing -> omitted
}
if *resp.Msg == "" {
    // Msg was set, but its value is an empty string
}
```

Anyway, let's set the `Data` field to be a valid JSON string. We use the type `json.RawMessage` to indicate that, when marshalling the entire `Response` struct, the contents of that field has to be preserved as-is. If not, JSON characters are going to be escaped, and the result will not be valid json:

```
prim, err := json.Marshal(msgs)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
resp.Data = prim // json.RawMessage underneath is a []byte
```